# PHP file list generated div boxes and first 2 of them empty

Tags: php, html, file, include

Here is my code.

First 2 divs are empty and out of order, how to do proper div boxes with included php files

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $dir    = 'folder/';
    $files = scandir($dir);
    $count=0;
    foreach($files as $file){
        $count++;
        echo '<div style="float:left; margin: 0 0 10px 10px;border:1px solid       #50A4AB;  width:200px"><br>';
        if(strpos($file,".php")){
            include($dir.$file);
        }
        echo '</div><br>';
        if($count==7){echo'<div style="clear:both;"></div><br>';}
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: EJP  thanks for your effort,its aprreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The scandir function returns '.' and '..' which you'll have to exclude from your results. That's why the first two divs are empty.

You should also check [the documentation for the scandir function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) for information about order.

Your html is malformed, causing the StackOverflow code highlighter to break and your indentation is inconsistent. You should put more an effort into making your examples easy to read when you're asking for help.

Comment: Ok thanks i am quite new here and as you said dont know how to use proper some of the functions, i had already asked this question but i didnt get an answer which helped enough so i have choosen different title maybe it was not good enough, i will try to do next time better ;) thanks for hints

Answer (score 0):

1. Everything @mqsoh said is correct. (+1)
2. Your code presents a massive security risk. Automatically loading all php files in a folder as includes is dangerous.  You should only load known, named files.
3. I've edited your question so that the code is more relevant.
4. You should include an if statement to the effect of:

`if ($file != "." && $file !="..") {

        // Do stuff here

    }`

In your code, like so:

```
foreach($files as $file){
    if ($file != "." && $file !="..") {
        $count++;
        echo '<div style="float:left; margin: 0 0 10px 10px;border:1px solid       #50A4AB;  width:200px"><br>';
        if(strpos($file,".php")){
            // This is a big security vulnerability
            include($dir.$file);
        }
        echo '</div><br>';
        if($count==7){echo'<div style="clear:both;"></div><br>';}
    }
}
```